# Confusion in git executable type to use for linux master and windows agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So i have the Jenkins master on a linux node and uses windows agent for some jobs. And i am using the workflow plugin. The script looks something like this 
as far as the agent uses is concerned.

```
node('windows_agent'){
    stage name: 'SCM checkout'
      //groovy code to checkout repo with app's source code with polling enabled (by using the Git.exe 1.9 for Windows)
      // Another groovy code to checkout repo with Jenkins's workflow source code withOUT polling enabled     

    stage name: '......'
    // continues 
    .
    .
    .
    .

  }
```

In the job configuration page, i have selected the `'Pipeline script from SCM'` and specified the git URL for the jenkins workflow repository. It is also set to poll
 the scm every 5mins using the Git for Linux (as i have to select one). I selected linux git as the master is a Linux node.  Now, the git polling is failing for the application 
 source code repo, as it tries to use the windows git.exe in the linux node. If i change this git executable to use the linux's one in the groovy code, the actual workflow execution
 will fails when it tries to checkout the code inside the windows agent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a checkout step with a [specific windows tool instance](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-scm-step-plugin#generic-scm-step).